# Fetching asmv1:assemblyIdentity from manifest

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, clickonce

After compilation the following is present in the app manifest, if I publish it by hand in VS the version picked is the first one, i.e. 3.9.0.3

```
<asmv1:assemblyIdentity name="MyApp.exe" version="3.9.0.3" publicKeyToken="0000000000000000" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="x86" type="win32" />
<description asmv2:iconFile="Logo.ico" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
<application />
<entryPoint>
   <assemblyIdentity name="MyApp" version="3.8.0.25806" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="x86" />
```

If instead I try running it in a MSBuild script and use

```
<Target Name="GetVersion">
   <Message Text="Getting version info..."/>
   <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="@(GetVersionAssembly)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies"
          ItemName="GetVersionAssemblyInfo"/>
   </GetAssemblyIdentity>
   <Message Text="%(GetVersionAssemblyInfo.Version)..."/>
</Target>
```

Where @(GetVersionAssembly) is the path to the executable, the 3.8.0.25806 version is picked, how do I get the published version rather than assembly version extracted in MSBuild, to make it match the manual publish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was use the MSBuild.Community.Tasks library and in the GetVersion target add below line, to allow the published version to be stored in the version.txt file. Not sure if there is a way of accessing the publish number within Visual Studio and increment that one when publishing with msbuild, which would prevent having to manually update these versions if you switch between the two ways of publishing. I would characterize this as a half solution since it still involve a manual step.

```
<Version VersionFile="version.txt" RevisionType="Increment"> <Output TaskParameter="Major" PropertyName="Major" /> <Output TaskParameter="Minor" PropertyName="Minor" /> <Output TaskParameter="Build" PropertyName="Build" /> <Output TaskParameter="Revision" PropertyName="Revision" /> </Version>
```

Within the script I then changed all %(GetVersionAssemblyInfo.Version) references to $(Major).$(Minor).$(Build).$(Revision)